# What is the relationship between friction and heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, friction

What is the relationship between friction and heat? What happens when friction occurs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Friction is a force that can either be a static friction force, which prevents any relative motion between two surfaces (prevents sliding between surfaces), or a kinetic friction force which acts in opposition to sliding motion that is already underway.

I'm guessing the reason for your question is the frequently used term "friction heating". Although the term is often used, it is a bit of a misnomer.  The raising of the temperature of the surfaces of material material due to them rubbing against one another is due to kinetic friction work, the product of the kinetic friction force and the distance it is applied, and not heat (a temperature difference). Subsequently there can be heat transfer from the elevated temperature surfaces to the cooler interior of the material, and other cooler areas of the environment, where there is a temperature difference. That is what is meant by "heating" in the term "friction heating".

A common example is rubbing ones hands together to warm them up in winter. The rubbing process is kinetic friction work. It raises the temperature of the surface of the skin (epidermis). Then heat transfers from the epidermis to the cooler dermis where the temperature sensing nerves are located, giving sensation of warmth.

But you can get the same warming effect by putting your hands near a fire in a fireplace. In that case your hands are being warmed by heat, in this case, radiant heat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a more correct term than "heating" for a process that raises the temperature of something?  Would you also consider the term Joule heating a misnomer?

Comment: @M.Enns Regarding the first question, if the rise in temperature of something is due to that something being exposed to something else whose temperature is higher, like exposing a gas to a higher temperature environment,, the correct term is heating. If the temperature rise is due solely to work being done on something, like the adiabatic compression of a gas, the increase in temperature is due to energy transfer by work. There is no simple term like “heating” that I am aware of that applies to raising temperature due to energy transfer by work.

Comment: Regarding the second question, from a purely thermodynamics viewpoint, the term “Joule heating”, like “friction heating”, is also something of a misnomer, only in the case of Joule heating the temperature rise is due to electrical work and not friction work. The increase in temperature of the resistor is an increase in the internal energy of the resistor. Heat is produced by the resulting temperature difference between the resistor at elevated temperature and things in the  environment that are at a lower temperature.  That, as I see it, is what is meant by “heating” in “Joule heating”.